# Assign variables name to values of array in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have array:
 a = [1,2,3,4]

```
yellow = a[0]
 red= a[1]
 blue = a[2]
 green = a[3]
```

Want to assign variables of each value of array in one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the number of elements *match the number of variables* you can use:

```
yellow, red, blue, green = a
```

If not, you can use:

```
yellow, red, blue, green = a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]
```